# What will be the best fit for this model?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I have one **Books** dataset for which I am trying to choose the best fit. I have tried with `LinearRegression`, `Decisiontree` and `Polynomial` one but none of them seems to be fitting to the curve. I have plotted 3 different curves, one features vs y_target and here are the plots:

**Curve_1**: Number of Ratings vs Ratings of book

[image]

**Curve_2**: Number of Text Reviews Count vs Ratings of book
[image]

**Curve_3**: Number of Pages In a book vs Ratings of book
[image]

So please tell me what will be the best model for this type of curves or i should analyse by any other way? The LinearRegression Output is:

**MSE**:  0.11599130999215618

**MAE**: 0.23

**Accuracy**:  0.11599130999215622

**R2 score**:  0.08296506346310017

What I think is logarithmic will be good but it may leave some of the data(data near to value 5 of every curve). I am very new to ML so please at least guide me a bit.

Here is the dataset link: https://www.kaggle.com/jealousleopard/goodreadsbooks

Quick View of Dataset:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

from scipy import stats

df = pd.read_csv("books.csv")

def drop_numerical_outliers(df, z_thresh=3):
    # Constrains will contain `True` or `False` depending on if it is a value below the threshold.
    constrains = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]) \
        .apply(lambda x: np.abs(stats.zscore(x)) < z_thresh, reduce=False) \
        .all(axis=1)
    # Drop (inplace) values set to be rejected
    df.drop(df.index[~constrains], inplace=True)

df.drop(['bookID','Unnamed: 10','isbn13','isbn','title','authors'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df.columns.values)

print("Shape After dropping columns: ",df.shape)
df.replace(to_replace = 'None', value = '0', inplace=True)

df = df[df['# num_pages'] != '0']   
print("Shape After Removing Rows with Num_pages 0: ",df.shape)

drop_numerical_outliers(df)
#print(df['# num_pages'].values[339])
print("Shape After Removing outliers: ",df.shape)

dummy_cols = ['language_code']
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=dummy_cols)
print("Shape After Categorizing dataset: ",df.shape)

#df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 3).all(axis=1)] 


x = df[df.columns.values]
x.drop(['average_rating'], axis=1, inplace=True)
y = df['average_rating']

x = x.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
y = y.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

x.fillna(0, inplace=True)
y.fillna(0, inplace=True)

#print(repr(df['# num_pages']))

#x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)
#print(df.head())

plt.scatter(x['# num_pages'],y, color = 'blue')
plt.xlabel("Number of Pages per Book")
plt.ylabel("Ratings")
plt.show()

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=4)

regr = LinearRegression()

#regr = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=0 )
regr.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_hat = regr.predict(x_test)
print(y_hat)
print(y_test.values)

print("MSE: ", mean_squared_error(y_test, y_hat))
print("Mean absolute error: %.2f" %np.mean(np.absolute(y_hat - y_test)))
print("Accuarcy: ", np.mean((y_hat - y_test)**2))
print('R2 score: ', r2_score(y_test, y_hat))
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by fitting the curve. You should give an example of the inputs of the model and the target of the model for better understanding.

Comment: @Angelo Provided the dataset link please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in machine learning, you really have to be mindful of the features you select for training. In your example, "Number of pages per Book" can't really help you because if a book is good, readers don't care about the number of pages. This fact is further solidified by the Curve_3 where data is very dense between rating 3 and 5. So you don't really need this feature.

Coming back to your problem, you are trying to predict the rating of a book. The plots in  curve 1 and 2 shows that one curve would not be able to pass through all the points (if it did, it will be an overfitted model). In this case, Linear regression will create a straight line at a value near 4 (on y-axis), because that is where most of the samples are.

If you use polynomial regression with different degrees, it will give you curve of that order but still it won't be able to pass all the point like you want to and in your case this is not even necessary.

What matters now is the evaluation metrics. Your MAE is very low which shows that your model can make good predictions (Low MAE good results, high MAE bad results). But your r2 is only 0.082. r2 ranges between 0 and 1, 1 being perfect predictions (might show overfitting) and 0 means a very bad model with bad prediction. The value of 0.082 shows that in some test values, the predictions are way off the target. So to summarise the results, your model can give you predictions with high accuracy but sometimes it will be way off the mark.

What I suggest, in this case, is to collect more relevant features and then train your model with a neural network if you want a better model.

I have analysed this dataset now and there are a couple of things I would like to mention here.

First I plotted a graph between y_test and y_hat(predicted values only for linear regression):[image: plot between y_test and y_hat]

As I had explained earlier that linear regression will create a straight line near value 4, you can see that all the predictions lie near to that line. Because of this it will generate high prediction error for the value where true rating is at 0 or 5. This is the reason why your r2_score is so low and this low score implies that your features are not good enough for this model.

If you go to this notebook:
https://www.kaggle.com/bellali/select-which-book-to-enjoy
you will see that there is no or very low correlation between the features and your target(book ratings). In addition, I also ran different algorithms with bad or quite similar results and this further solidifies the fact that the features do not explain your target.

Another thing to mention here is that this dataset is merely for exploratory purposes and not for making predictions. You can see a couple of kernels for this data which are doing different kinds of analysis and this is the real purpose of this dataset.

This is a prime example of "A model is as good as the data".

Comment: I have just edited the question with Dataset link, please have a look.

Comment: Thanks its a great explanation! But how do you determine that the following dataset is for making predictions or for exploratory?

Comment: Analyse the relationship between response (label variable) and predictors (features). If the response var is dependent on any other feature in a dataset, you can use that feature and make a prediction models. Else, you most probably could not. Sometimes, the author also indicates a suitable use for a dataset.
Though, I have to say that most of the time, it can be assessed more by common sense than actual scientific/mathematical investigation.

Comment: e.g. If you want to guess a rating of a book what do you think would factor most? In my opinion, factors like target_AgeGroup(children, teenagers, adults etc.), genre(Horror, Romance, Action etc.), author_renown(something to indicate how famous the author is) would give a much better rating prediction than number_of_pages or ratings_count. Interesting thing to note here is that if you were trying to predict how famous the book was or how much it had earned than this "rating_counts" would have been quite an important factor.

Comment: Another important thing to note here is that, in real life scenario, mostly, you don't have to determine if the dataset is for prediction or exploration. The first part of any project is "What is the problem that is needed to be solved?" and then you gather data according to that problem and not the other way around. If there is a publisher who receives manuscripts from authors to publish would create a dataset that would predict ratings of a book. If there is a bookstore owner he would want this exploratory dataset so he can put most sought out books on display.

Comment: this cleared out a lot of stuff running inside my brain, thank you :)